# How to Convert Multi<Document>into Map<Long,List<Offer> in Quarkus Reactive With Mongo Client Library

Tags: java, quarkus-reactive

Im trying to read collections data from MongoDB Using ReactiveMongoClient in Quarkus.
Im getting Multi and tried to map to my custom object and prepare list and convert into Map<Long,List> offersMapGroubyCustomerId but no luck . anyone please help me on this.
I tried like this in my scheduler in Quarkus Reactive Programming .

Code Snippet :

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class OfferScheduler {

  @Inject
    ReactiveMongoClient reactiveMongoClient;

    @Scheduled(cron = "{cron.expr}")
    public void publishPropositions() {
        getOffersCollection()
                .aggregate(pipeline())
                .map(this::mapOffer)
                .collect()
                .with(Collectors.groupingBy(Offer::getMemberId))
                .onItem().transformToUni(this::iterateOfferMap);
    }

    private Uni<Void> iterateOfferMap(Map<Long, List<Offer>> item) {
       // I need to iterate this map here
        return Uni.createFrom().nullItem();
    }
    
    private Offer mapOffer(Document document) {
        return Offer.builder()
                .memberId(document.getLong(MEMBER_ID))
                .offerId(document.getLong(OFFER_ID))
                .remainingUsage(document.getInteger(REMAINING_USAGE))
                .offerName(document.getString(PROPOSITION_TYPE))
                .status(document.getString(STATUS))
                .build();
    }
    
    private ReactiveMongoCollection<Document> getOffersCollection() {
        return reactiveMongoClient.getDatabase("database").getCollection("offer");
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Uni#call` (or `Uni#chain`):

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "{cron.expr}")
    @NonBlocking // I think you might need this annotation but I haven't tested it
    public void publishPropositions() {
        getOffersCollection()
                .aggregate(pipeline())
                .map(this::mapOffer)
                .collect()
                .with(Collectors.groupingBy(Offer::getMemberId))
                .call(this::iterateOfferMap);
    }

    private Uni<Void> iterateOfferMap(Map<Long, List<Offer>> item) {
        // Do something with the map
        return Uni.createFrom().voidItem();
    }
```

But the `publishPropositions` method is not reactive, are you sure that for this use case `MongoClient` isn't more appropriate (instead of `ReactiveMongoClient`)?